# Два фона по бокам во всю ширину

Tags: html, css

Получается, что левая и правая части - разные градиенты сверху и заливка фона разная у них: у одного - зеленая, у другого - белая. А по центру - div шириной 1000 пикселей...

Вот у меня дилемма. Как сверстать так, чтоб 2 разных фона по бокам растягивались на всю ширину экрана, но при этом центральная часть была стабильно 1000px?

Меня интересует верстка самого каркаса.

**Добавлено.**

Да нет, просто есть такой макет...

```
<di v class="left">тут должен быть левый градиент зеленый в салатовый,</div>
<di v class="center">тут должен быть блок 1000 пикселей</div>
<di v class="right">тут должен быть левый градиент зеленый в белый,</div>
```

Какие CSS для каждого прописать, чтоб работало нормально? Ну или как их расставить? Может 1 в другой надо поместить или ещё что-то?..

Comment: Опиши свою проблему по подробней.. ты используешь iframe или что то другое? 

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.

Comment: Может поговорите с горе дизайнером, я думаю ему просто было облом правую сторону делать, мол и так понятно, особенно это касается исчезновения зеленоватого фона после градиента.

Answer (score 1):

Если разрывается голова от невозможности без яваскрипта сделать вёрстку блоками, может плюнуть и сделать таблицей? 3 ячейки, первая и последняя шириной "*", должно сработать в теории...

Comment: А можно подробнее про таблицы с шириной "*"... не встречал такого...

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, записывалось так. Ширина "*" означает заполнение остатка пространства. Столбцы со звёздами должны делить это пространство между собой...

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td width="*"></td><td width="1000"></td><td width="*"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

Может попробовать 100% ширины у крайних ячеек таблицы... и 1000px по середине через CSS...

Comment: Спасибо огромное... я так заверстался дивами, что про таблицы совершенно и забыл :) Считал, верстка таблицами - каменный веком. Сейчас буду снова возвращаться понемногу и к таблицам. Помог следующий код:

    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" border="0">
       <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td width="1000px"></td>
          <td></td>
       </tr>
    </table>

Comment: понимаю, дивы удобно и к ним быстро привыкаешь, но не всегда имеют тривиальное решение :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:
Левый градиент через background для html
Правый для body

---

Не всем этот способ нравиться: 2 div пустых будут

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.left{
  width: 50%;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.right{
  width: 50%;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.content{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: А как ты сделаешь чтоб он растягивался да ещё и на пол экрана только??? Тут получается, что надо 2 растягивающихся градиента... и все бы ничего, можно было б и по 50% кинуть... но тут надо ещё и по центру чтобы было 1000 пикселей... а Пиксели с % неособо дружат...

Comment: Да, с body и html не подумавши ляпнул. I'am sorry. Я добавил другой вариант, может пригодится, но лично мне он не по душе.

Comment: Такой вариант я тоже пробовал... но тогда если появляется прокрутка то неизвестно как сделать боковые дивы по высоте... 

 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;

И так неканает даже...

Answer (score 0):

Вот посмотри [тут](http://freedom.dp.ua/hashcode/index.html), только картинки нужно нормально вырезать, но сам лайаут такой как надо (два половинки с разным фоном, высота на весь экран, ширина 1000 пикселей), кроссбраузерность проверял в ие7-8 и фф